# swift afnetworking ssl pinning

Tags: swift, ssl, afnetworking, pinning

var manager: AFHTTPSessionManager

```
init() {
    manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

    let securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.Certificate)
    let certificatePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("c38acbe05a6328ee", ofType: "crt")!
    let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: certificatePath)!

    securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = [certificateData]
    securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false
    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = false

    manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy
}
```

I've been trying to get this working for some time now.  Swift documentation is sparce, but I'm getting better at reading obj-c.  The cert is in PEM format, I've tried that and converting to .der format.  Der format blows up in init(), .PEM format blows up in evaluateServerTrust.  I tried in AFNetworking 2.5.1 and upgraded to 3.0.4 - same issue.  I've tried every combination of true and false for the following.

securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = false

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After much research and trial  ...  I decide to move to Alamofire 3.0 and the solution came.
Note the following:
The certificate must be in .der format.  Mine was in .pem format.
My certifcate was for the "leaf" i.e, the certificate chain was not included.
For iOS 9.0 I had to add the ATS transport for my server.

Working example:

```
var manager: Manager

init() {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "myserver.com": .PinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
            validateCertificateChain: false,
            validateHost: true
        )
    ]

    manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
                                serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
}



let email = defaults.objectForKey("email") as? String
let beacon = defaults.objectForKey("beacon") as? String

let credential = NSURLCredential(user: email!, password: beacon!, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)

manager.request(.GET, url, encoding: .JSON)
.authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
.responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let data):
        print(data)
        self.delegate?.didReceivePersonResults!(data as! NSDictionary)
    case .Failure(let error):
        print(error)
        self.delegate?.didReceivePersonError!("Server Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: The iOS 9 ATS comment ...  add the following to your info.plist
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
      <dict>
         <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
               <key>myserver.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
         <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>